# Random signature in Gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I know that Gmail has been caching email signature since December 2013, but is there a way to insert in my signature a RANDOM image?

I have a server that creates a random image on request  and display it every time you refresh the page. But when I link to that "random image generator" in the Gmail signature, it CACHES it ONCE then it never seem to update it, even if the image change,

I tried JPG, PNG, PHP extensions (and manually changed the image under it) but it didn't work. I also tried "image.php?u=94358" or similar and that didn't work either

Is there a way to give a dynamic url to Gmail signature like "image.php?date={date(Ymd)}" so that Gmail itself, BEFORE sending the email would generate a different file URL? Ex: image.php?date=20140829 so it would always refresh for every new emails?

(or any other ways)

Thank you

Comment: Probably not possible, because [Gmail now shows images to users](http://gmailblog.blogspot.ch/2013/12/images-now-showing.html) after caching them

Answer (score 5):

This is totally possible, and actually super easy.
You'll just have to output a php file as an image.

The simple way:

#### 1. Create a directory to serve your image (mywebsite.com/signature/).

#### 2. Add a folder containing your images:

images/

- image-0.png
- image-1.png
- image-2.png
- image-3.png

#### 3. Add index.php to the root with the following code:

```
    $image_count = 5; // lets say you have six images from 0-5
    $number = rand( 0 , $image_count );

    // fetch random image from directory
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $file = $dir.'/images/image-'.$number.'.png';

    // write out
    $type = 'image/png';
    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
```

#### 4. Add an .htaccess file to the root with the following code to trick the browser into thinking index.php is a static image:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^logo.png index.php [L]
```

#### 5. Add your random image to your mail signature like any other image. (http://mywebsite.com/signature/logo.png)

#### 6. Et voilà!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but like i said, Gmail caches images. I already tried a php script to do that

Comment: Yes. Gmail caches images in *your* compose window, but the receiver will see a random image. Isn't that the most important part of this? Imageproof: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2e3a985.jpg